# . or operator expected after expression in GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written a simple program to find largest of two number in prolog

```
domains
    x,y,z=integer
predicates
    bigger(x,y,z)
clauses
    bigger(X,Y,Z):-
        X>Y,Z=X.
    bigger(X,Y,Z):-
        X<Y,Z=Y.
goal
    bigger(5,7,X).
```

but whenever I run the program I get the error:

```
compiling /home/prabin/large_number.pl for byte code...
/home/prabin/large_number.pl:2:5: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
/home/prabin/large_number.pl:11:5: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
    2 error(s)
compilation failed
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source code is for Visual Prolog (or the older TurboProlog). Delete:

```
domains
    x,y,z=integer
predicates
    bigger(x,y,z)
clauses
```

and

```
goal
    bigger(5,7,X).
```

leaving only

```
bigger(X,Y,Z):-
    X>Y,Z=X.
bigger(X,Y,Z):-
    X<Y,Z=Y.
```

After saving the fixed code, you can type the goal at the top-level interpreter:

```
| ?- bigger(5,7,X).

X = 7

yes
```